# Bootstrap: Change breadcrumb's active text color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

I want to make the text color About us of the breadcrumb to black but its not working.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="disabled"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
</ol>
```

I tried following CSS but it didn't work.

```
.breadcrumb > .active {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any idea why it is not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As per Bootstrap's [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#breadcrumbs) breadcrumb's `active` item
>   doesn't contain any link inside.

This is logical as last item shows current active page and it shouldn't be clickable so `<a>` element is excess here.

Use the standard Bootstrap structure for breadcrumbs i.e.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  <li class="active">Data</li>
</ol>
```

Here are two possible ways of overriding active text color:

**Method #01:**

1. Go to [Customizing Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) page.
2. Move to [Breadcrumbs](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#breadcrumbs) section.
3. Override the default value of `@breadcrumb-active-color` varaible with the value that you need i.e. `#000`.
4. Move to Download section and press **"Compile and Download"** Button.

---

**Method #02:**

You will need to override Bootstrap styles in your custom css file.

```
.breadcrumb >.active {
   color: black;
}
```

---

However if you still need link inside `active` item you need to change selector accordingly i.e:

```
.breadcrumb >.active a {
   color: black;
}
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.breadcrumb > .active,
.breadcrumb > .active a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  <li class="active">Data(Without Link)</li>
</ol>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Data(With Link)</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the CSS to the `a` within the .active li:

```css
.breadcrumb >.active a{
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="breadcrumb">
     <li class="disabled"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

CSS Code:

```
.breadcrumb > .active a{
color: #333333; <!-- Or your color preference -->
}
```

Html Code:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Active Link</a></li>
</ol>
```

Here's an implementation of Basic Bootstrap Framework to create a CMS template from scratch: [Link](http://piyusharora.co/bootstrap/bootstrap-cms-template/index.html)